# .NET 3.5 and SP1 install question - single installer

Tags: .net, installation, .net-3.5

Does this install .NET 3.5 and SP1?
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ab99342f-5d1a-413d-8319-81da479ab0d7&displaylang=en

or is there no single installer yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this installs the full 3.5 framework and SP1.

The reason the file is so small is that it is the "web bootstrapper" installer. It will start the install process, determine which files you need, and then download the appropriate files as part of the install.

If you need the full installer up front, check out [this link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe), provided towards the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

lower on page

Full Package
To download the full package, rather than the bootstrapper, click on the link below:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe